# How can I loop over an array of arrays created with flat()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, nested

I have combined 3 JSON files into a single array using flat(), and then looped through the array to output its contents in the console. It outputs an array of arrays created from the 3 JSON files below.

Here's the console output:

```
{books: Array(3)}books: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]__proto__: Object
{movies: Array(3)}movies: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]__proto__: Object
{posts: Array(3)}posts: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]__proto__: Object
```

I'm having trouble looping through each of the inner arrays to access their properties/values. Can anyone please lend some assistance? Thank you!

Here's my code...

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let finalResult;

const urls = ['books', 'movies', 'posts'];

Promise.all(
urls.map(url =>
    fetch('json/' + url + '.json')
        .then(e => e.json())
    )
).then(data => {
    finalResult = data.flat();

    finalResult.forEach(array => {
      console.log(array); // returns the array of arrays I want to loop through to get the property-values
    });
});
```

books.json

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "title": "Eloquent JavaScript, Second Edition",
      "description": "JavaScript lies at the heart of almost every modern web application, from social apps to the newest browser-based games. Though simple for beginners to pick up and play with, JavaScript is a flexible, complex language that you can use to build full-scale applications."
    },
    {
      "title": "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns",
      "description": "With Learning JavaScript Design Patterns, you'll learn how to write beautiful, structured, and maintainable JavaScript by applying classical and modern design patterns to the language. If you want to keep your code efficient, more manageable, and up-to-date with the latest best practices, this book is for you."
    },
    {
      "title": "Speaking JavaScript",
      "description": "Like it or not, JavaScript is everywhere these days-from browser to server to mobile-and now you, too, need to learn the language or dive deeper than you have. This concise book guides you into and through JavaScript, written by a veteran programmer who once found himself in the same position."
    }
  ]
}
```

movies.json

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "title": "History of the World Part I",
      "description": "A 1981 American sketch comedy film written, produced, and directed by Mel Brooks. Brooks also stars in the film, playing five roles: Moses, Comicus the stand-up philosopher, Tomás de Torquemada, King Louis XVI, and Jacques, le garçon de pisse."
    },
    {
      "title": "Jaws",
      "description": "a 1975 American thriller film directed by Steven Spielberg, based on Peter Benchley's 1974 novel of the same name. In the film, a man-eating great white shark attacks beachgoers at a summer resort town, prompting police chief Martin Brody (Roy Scheider) to hunt it with the help of a marine biologist (Richard Dreyfuss) and a professional shark hunter (Robert Shaw). "
    },
    {
      "title": "The Exorcist",
      "description": "When a 12-year-old girl is possessed by a mysterious entity, her mother seeks the help of two priests to save her."
    }
  ]
}
```

posts.json

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "title": "Done",
      "description": "I can't take it anymore."
    },
    {
      "title": "Finished",
      "description": "The story of a young man who has finished his sandwich."
    },
    {
      "title": "Concluded",
      "description": "An epic take of a meeting that has conluded."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How your expected output looks like? Also how data looks like `data: {books: [...], posts: [...], movies: [...]}` ?

Comment: It's not so much the output...I want to be able access the inner array properties and values so I can use that data. I have a <div></div> in my html and I would like to be able to update the innerHTML to list all of the book titles (book.title) or movie descriptions (movie.description) and such. Does this answer your question?

Comment: you already have 2 answers for you question, you can check if any matches your requirements, if not you can comment them and tell why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.entries` and destructuring.

```js
const finalResult = [{"books":[{"title":"Eloquent JavaScript, Second Edition","description":"JavaScript lies at the heart of almost every modern web application, from social apps to the newest browser-based games. Though simple for beginners to pick up and play with, JavaScript is a flexible, complex language that you can use to build full-scale applications."},{"title":"Learning JavaScript Design Patterns","description":"With Learning JavaScript Design Patterns, you'll learn how to write beautiful, structured, and maintainable JavaScript by applying classical and modern design patterns to the language. If you want to keep your code efficient, more manageable, and up-to-date with the latest best practices, this book is for you."},{"title":"Speaking JavaScript","description":"Like it or not, JavaScript is everywhere these days-from browser to server to mobile-and now you, too, need to learn the language or dive deeper than you have. This concise book guides you into and through JavaScript, written by a veteran programmer who once found himself in the same position."}]},
    {"movies":[{"title":"History of the World Part I","description":"A 1981 American sketch comedy film written, produced, and directed by Mel Brooks. Brooks also stars in the film, playing five roles: Moses, Comicus the stand-up philosopher, Tomás de Torquemada, King Louis XVI, and Jacques, le garçon de pisse."},{"title":"Jaws","description":"a 1975 American thriller film directed by Steven Spielberg, based on Peter Benchley's 1974 novel of the same name. In the film, a man-eating great white shark attacks beachgoers at a summer resort town, prompting police chief Martin Brody (Roy Scheider) to hunt it with the help of a marine biologist (Richard Dreyfuss) and a professional shark hunter (Robert Shaw). "},{"title":"The Exorcist","description":"When a 12-year-old girl is possessed by a mysterious entity, her mother seeks the help of two priests to save her."}]},
    {"posts":[{"title":"Done","description":"I can't take it anymore."},{"title":"Finished","description":"The story of a young man who has finished his sandwich."},{"title":"Concluded","description":"An epic take of a meeting that has conluded."}]}]

finalResult.forEach(obj => {
  // destructure first entry key, value pair.
  const [[type, array]] = Object.entries(obj);
  console.log('-----------> Type: ', type);
  array.forEach(item => console.log(item));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted, cause you didn't specify exact output, but I think you get a point how can it be done.

`Object.entries` / `Object.keys` / `Object.values` is something what you are looking for:

```js
const books = {"books":[{"title":"Eloquent JavaScript, Second Edition","description":"JavaScript lies at the heart of almost every modern web application, from social apps to the newest browser-based games. Though simple for beginners to pick up and play with, JavaScript is a flexible, complex language that you can use to build full-scale applications."},{"title":"Learning JavaScript Design Patterns","description":"With Learning JavaScript Design Patterns, you'll learn how to write beautiful, structured, and maintainable JavaScript by applying classical and modern design patterns to the language. If you want to keep your code efficient, more manageable, and up-to-date with the latest best practices, this book is for you."},{"title":"Speaking JavaScript","description":"Like it or not, JavaScript is everywhere these days-from browser to server to mobile-and now you, too, need to learn the language or dive deeper than you have. This concise book guides you into and through JavaScript, written by a veteran programmer who once found himself in the same position."}]}
const movies = {"movies":[{"title":"History of the World Part I","description":"A 1981 American sketch comedy film written, produced, and directed by Mel Brooks. Brooks also stars in the film, playing five roles: Moses, Comicus the stand-up philosopher, Tomás de Torquemada, King Louis XVI, and Jacques, le garçon de pisse."},{"title":"Jaws","description":"a 1975 American thriller film directed by Steven Spielberg, based on Peter Benchley's 1974 novel of the same name. In the film, a man-eating great white shark attacks beachgoers at a summer resort town, prompting police chief Martin Brody (Roy Scheider) to hunt it with the help of a marine biologist (Richard Dreyfuss) and a professional shark hunter (Robert Shaw). "},{"title":"The Exorcist","description":"When a 12-year-old girl is possessed by a mysterious entity, her mother seeks the help of two priests to save her."}]}
const posts = {"posts":[{"title":"Done","description":"I can't take it anymore."},{"title":"Finished","description":"The story of a young man who has finished his sandwich."},{"title":"Concluded","description":"An epic take of a meeting that has conluded."}]}

const yourThen = (data) => {
  const finalResult = data.map(e => Object.entries(e)).flat()
  finalResult.forEach(([k, v]) => console.log(k, v))
  return finalResult
}

yourThen([books, posts, movies])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```